# The EntryPoint setup.bat is not found -Deploy Service Fabric Application

Tags: debugging, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-releases

Angular project azure pipeline build is successful , while doing release there is error.
AZURE CI - OK
AZURE CD - FAIL (*The EntryPoint setup.bat is not found*.)
[image: AZURE RELEASE]

**LOGDETAILS**

```
[![2023-02-16T06:34:23.2807130Z ##\[debug\]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy Service Fabric Application'
```

==============================================================================
2023-02-16T06:34:23.3540814Z Task         : Service Fabric application deployment
2023-02-16T06:34:23.3541277Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Service Fabric application to a cluster
2023-02-16T06:34:23.3541644Z Version      : 1.205.0
2023-02-16T06:34:23.3541964Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-02-16T06:34:23.3542438Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/service-fabric-deploy
2023-02-16T06:34:23.3543016Z ==============================================================================
2023-02-16T06:34:25.1957417Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.11.0 commit 7ff27a3e0bdd6f7b06690ae5f5b63cb84d0f23f4
2023-02-16T06:34:25.5129968Z ##[debug]Entering C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\deploy.ps1.
2023-02-16T06:34:25.5282938Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\task.json
2023-02-16T06:34:25.7973463Z ##[debug]Loaded 83 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:25.8023935Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2023-02-16T06:34:25.8057304Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2023-02-16T06:34:25.9847337Z ##[debug]Loaded 83 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.0041645Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\ServiceFabricHelpers\ServiceFabricHelpers.psm1'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.0293333Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\ServiceFabricHelpers\module.json
2023-02-16T06:34:26.0696198Z ##[debug]Loaded 18 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.0723633Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.0746620Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\ServiceFabricHelpers\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2023-02-16T06:34:26.1275766Z ##[debug]Loaded 18 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.1914865Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2026748Z ##[debug] LiteralDirectory: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\ServiceFabricHelpers'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2043250Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: '*.ps1'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2458016Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2487195Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\ServiceFabricHelpers*.ps1'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2537018Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2573874Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'True'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2592344Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.2608466Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.4271099Z ##[debug]Paths: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\ServiceFabricHelpers

2023-02-16T06:34:26.4310374Z ##[debug] CommonHelpers.ps1
2023-02-16T06:34:26.4326154Z ##[debug] Connect-ServiceFabricClusterFromServiceEndpoint.ps1
2023-02-16T06:34:26.4342019Z ##[debug] Get-ServiceFabricEncryptedText.ps1
2023-02-16T06:34:26.4357753Z ##[debug] SFOperations.ps1
2023-02-16T06:34:26.4378359Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.5122541Z ##[debug]Total found: 4
2023-02-16T06:34:26.5143271Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.5160094Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Connect-ServiceFabricClusterFromServiceEndpoint'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.5176598Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Remove-ClientCertificate'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.5683416Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Get-ServiceFabricEncryptedText'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.5684780Z ##[debug]Exporting variable 'SF_Operations'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.5893602Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Publish-Telemetry'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6036943Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Get-SfSdkVersion'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6080008Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Trace-WarningIfCertificateNotPresentInLocalCertStore'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6148604Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Connect-ServiceFabricClusterFromServiceEndpoint'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6230291Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Get-ServiceFabricEncryptedText'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6280133Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Get-SfSdkVersion'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6322248Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Publish-Telemetry'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6374576Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Remove-ClientCertificate'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6397996Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Trace-WarningIfCertificateNotPresentInLocalCertStore'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6430201Z ##[debug]Importing variable 'SF_Operations'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6526506Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\PowershellHelpers\PowershellHelpers.psm1'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.6877730Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\PowershellHelpers\module.json
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7028256Z ##[debug]Loaded 3 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7062567Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7089459Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\PowershellHelpers\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7246420Z ##[debug]Loaded 3 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7460307Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Invoke-ActionWithRetries'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7478679Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Get-TempDirectoryPath'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7499849Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Get-TempDirectoryPath'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7520353Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Invoke-ActionWithRetries'.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7785991Z ##[debug]INPUT_PUBLISHPROFILEPATH: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a**\drop\projectartifacts**\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7876521Z Searching for path: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a**\drop\projectartifacts**\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7901060Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7921975Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a**\drop\projectartifacts**\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7954374Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7976246Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a**\drop\projectartifacts**\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.7995775Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2023-02-16T06:34:26.8017147Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'True'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.8038028Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:26.8059320Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.4825264Z ##[debug]Path: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\projectartifacts\METalUISFService\METal.UI\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml
2023-02-16T06:34:27.4874819Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.4896994Z ##[debug]Total found: 1
2023-02-16T06:34:27.4922115Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.5100785Z ##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\projectartifacts\METalUISFService\METal.UI\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.5114805Z Found path: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\projectartifacts\METalUISFService\METal.UI\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml
2023-02-16T06:34:27.6704378Z ##[debug]INPUT_APPLICATIONPACKAGEPATH: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\applicationpackage'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.6715597Z Searching for path: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\applicationpackage
2023-02-16T06:34:27.6954333Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.6977019Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\applicationpackage'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.6997296Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'True'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.7034444Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.7059530Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\applicationpackage'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.7084865Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2023-02-16T06:34:27.7104710Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.7129481Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'True'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.7154737Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.8997196Z ##[debug]Path: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\applicationpackage
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9013786Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9028693Z ##[debug]Total found: 1
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9044096Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9059960Z ##[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\applicationpackage'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9070615Z Found path: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\applicationpackage
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9089593Z ##[debug]INPUT_SERVICECONNECTIONNAME: '61b960bd-64f6-42e9-b8d3-fa799c0d99fc'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9189445Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_URL_61b960bd-64f6-42e9-b8d3-fa799c0d99fc: 'tcp://sfmetaldev.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000/'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9215189Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_AUTH_61b960bd-64f6-42e9-b8d3-fa799c0d99fc: '********'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9236666Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_DATA_61b960bd-64f6-42e9-b8d3-fa799c0d99fc: '{}'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9260749Z ##[debug]INPUT_COPYPACKAGETIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9297096Z ##[debug]INPUT_REGISTERPACKAGETIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9316155Z ##[debug]INPUT_COMPRESSPACKAGE: 'true'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9350002Z ##[debug]INPUT_SKIPUPGRADESAMETYPEANDVERSION: 'true'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9368446Z ##[debug]INPUT_SKIPPACKAGEVALIDATION: 'false'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9387016Z ##[debug]INPUT_UNREGISTERUNUSEDVERSIONS: 'true'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9405377Z ##[debug]INPUT_CONFIGUREDOCKERSETTINGS: 'false'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9423687Z ##[debug]INPUT_OVERRIDEAPPLICATIONPARAMETER: 'false'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9537832Z ##[debug]Entering Connect-ServiceFabricClusterFromServiceEndpoint.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9566062Z ##[debug] ClusterConnectionParameters: 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9592514Z ##[debug] ConnectedServiceEndpoint: '@{Url=tcp://sfmetaldev.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000/; Data=; Auth=}'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9614091Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\TlsHelper_\TlsHelper_.psm1'.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9844537Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\TlsHelper_/module.json
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9951667Z ##[debug]Loaded 3 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9974296Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2023-02-16T06:34:27.9993679Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\ps_modules\TlsHelper_\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0106268Z ##[debug]Loaded 3 strings.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0121361Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Add-Tls12InSession'.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0135831Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Assert-TlsError'.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0151754Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Add-Tls12InSession'.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0168455Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Assert-TlsError'.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0190517Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Get-TempDirectoryPath'.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0205027Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Invoke-ActionWithRetries'.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.0785987Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2023-02-16T06:34:28.2683150Z Imported cluster client certificate with thumbprint '***'.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.2994740Z Successfully connected to cluster.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.3062565Z ##[debug]Leaving Connect-ServiceFabricClusterFromServiceEndpoint.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.4339705Z ##[debug]INPUT_APPLICATIONPARAMETERPATH: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.4656894Z Searching for path: C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5182852Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5185451Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5187054Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5188928Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5190662Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5192321Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'True'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5193733Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.5195127Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6231110Z ##[debug]No paths.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6253746Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6269325Z ##[debug]Total found: 0
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6284931Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6310243Z No items were found with search pattern C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6358086Z ##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\BA\vsts-agent_work\r1\a_METal Development UI-CI\drop\projectartifacts\METalUISFService\METal.UI\PublishProfiles..\ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6381864Z ##[debug]INPUT_OVERRIDEPUBLISHPROFILESETTINGS: 'true'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6390471Z Overriding upgrade settings specified in publish profile with the settings specified in the Azure Pipelines task.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6408951Z ##[debug]INPUT_ISUPGRADE: 'true'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6452721Z ##[debug]INPUT_UPGRADEMODE: 'Monitored'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6487858Z ##[debug]INPUT_UPGRADEREPLICASETCHECKTIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6506804Z ##[debug]INPUT_REPLICAQUORUMTIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6538632Z ##[debug]INPUT_TIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6558080Z ##[debug]INPUT_FORCERESTART: 'false'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6576850Z ##[debug]INPUT_FAILUREACTION: 'Rollback'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6608550Z ##[debug]INPUT_HEALTHCHECKRETRYTIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6627393Z ##[debug]INPUT_HEALTHCHECKWAITDURATIONSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6645708Z ##[debug]INPUT_HEALTHCHECKSTABLEDURATIONSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6664068Z ##[debug]INPUT_UPGRADEDOMAINTIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6691218Z ##[debug]INPUT_CONSIDERWARNINGASERROR: 'false'
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6718089Z ##[debug]INPUT_DEFAULTSERVICETYPEHEALTHPOLICY (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6746484Z ##[debug]INPUT_MAXPERCENTUNHEALTHYDEPLOYEDAPPLICATIONS (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6774218Z ##[debug]INPUT_UPGRADETIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.6801075Z ##[debug]INPUT_SERVICETYPEHEALTHPOLICYMAP (empty)
2023-02-16T06:34:29.7138767Z Service fabric SDK version: 6.0.1028.9590.
2023-02-16T06:34:29.7750044Z ##[debug]INPUT_USEDIFFPACKAGE: 'true'
2023-02-16T06:36:16.8074038Z ##[debug]Join-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code" "ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd"
2023-02-16T06:36:16.8142028Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd
2023-02-16T06:36:16.8153154Z ##[debug]Length: 94
2023-02-16T06:36:16.8172350Z ##[debug]
2023-02-16T06:36:16.8192676Z ##[debug]Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd"
2023-02-16T06:36:16.8239296Z ##[debug]True
2023-02-16T06:36:16.8251763Z ##[debug]
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0491594Z ##[debug]System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.FabricImageBuilderValidationException: The EntryPoint TheProject.Identity.Service.exe is not found.
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0527535Z ##[debug]FileName: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_20507114412945\nocz40ci.2x3\applicationpackage\METal.UIPkg\ServiceManifest.xml
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0668701Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.TraceAndThrowValidationErrorWithFileName(FabricErrorCode fabricErrorCode, String type, String fileName, String format, Object[] args)
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0671235Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ServiceManifestValidator.ValidateEntryPointPath(String serviceManifestFileName, FileLocator fileLocator, String program, Boolean isExternalExecutable)
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0673473Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ServiceManifestValidator.ValidateServiceManifests(ApplicationTypeContext context, Boolean isComposeDeployment)
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0675729Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ServiceManifestValidator.Validate(ApplicationTypeContext applicationTypeContext, Boolean isComposeDeployment, Boolean isSFVolumeDiskServiceEnabled)
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0678009Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.ValidateApplicationType(ApplicationTypeContext applicationTypeContext, Boolean isComposeDeployment)
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0680055Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.d__22.MoveNext()
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0681744Z ##[debug]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0683248Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0684859Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2023-02-16T06:37:30.0686639Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.d__21.MoveNext()
2023-02-16T06:37:35.7477697Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_JOBID: '6d11c418-efa2-55ff-7808-6fa3bbd35dfa'
2023-02-16T06:37:35.7774611Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=TaskHub;feature=ServiceFabricDeploy]{"OperationId":"TestApplicationPackage","ExceptionData":"System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.FabricImageBuilderValidationException;|C:\BA\vsts-agent\_work\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\deploy.ps1|116","JobId":"6d11c418-efa2-55ff-7808-6fa3bbd35dfa","SDKVersion":"6.0.1028.9590"}
2023-02-16T06:37:35.8492879Z ##[debug]Leaving C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\deploy.ps1.
2023-02-16T06:37:35.8496982Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2023-02-16T06:37:35.8531605Z ##[debug]Error record:
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9163434Z ##[debug]Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : The EntryPoint TheProject.Identity.Service.exe is not found.
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9182323Z ##[debug]FileName: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_20507114412945\nocz40ci.2x3\applicationpackage\METal.UIPkg\ServiceManifest.xml
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9194414Z ##[debug]At C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\deploy.ps1:116 char:31
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9207810Z ##[debug]+ ... kageValid = Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage -ApplicationPackageP ...
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9221199Z ##[debug]+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9234932Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage], FabricImageBuilderValidati    onException
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9248389Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestApplicationPackageErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestApplicationPackage
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9261320Z ##[debug]
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9279715Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9839342Z ##[debug]at , C:\BA\vsts-agent_work_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.205.0\deploy.ps1: line 116
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9863369Z ##[debug]at , : line 1
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9867127Z ##[debug]at , : line 22
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9877531Z ##[debug]at , : line 18
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9887776Z ##[debug]at , : line 1
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9903585Z ##[debug]Exception:
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9956962Z ##[debug]System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.FabricImageBuilderValidationException: The EntryPoint TheProject.Identity.Service.exe is not found.
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9971720Z ##[debug]FileName: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_20507114412945\nocz40ci.2x3\applicationpackage\METal.UIPkg\ServiceManifest.xml
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9985624Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.TraceAndThrowValidationErrorWithFileName(FabricErrorCode fabricErrorCode, String type, String fileName, String format, Object[] args)
2023-02-16T06:37:35.9999153Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ServiceManifestValidator.ValidateEntryPointPath(String serviceManifestFileName, FileLocator fileLocator, String program, Boolean isExternalExecutable)
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0012302Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ServiceManifestValidator.ValidateServiceManifests(ApplicationTypeContext context, Boolean isComposeDeployment)
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0026010Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ServiceManifestValidator.Validate(ApplicationTypeContext applicationTypeContext, Boolean isComposeDeployment, Boolean isSFVolumeDiskServiceEnabled)
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0041068Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.ValidateApplicationType(ApplicationTypeContext applicationTypeContext, Boolean isComposeDeployment)
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0054805Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.d__22.MoveNext()
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0069353Z ##[debug]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0083295Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0097843Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0111638Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.d__21.MoveNext()
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0444063Z ##[error]The EntryPoint setup.bat is not found.
FileName: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_20507114412945\nocz40ci.2x3\applicationpackage\METal.UIPkg\ServiceManifest.xml
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0459263Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]The EntryPoint TheProject.Identity.Service.exe is not found.%0D%0AFileName: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_20507114412945\nocz40ci.2x3\applicationpackage\METal.UIPkg\ServiceManifest.xml
2023-02-16T06:37:36.0462350Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2023-02-16T06:37:36.1069769Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Service Fabric Application][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

there was memory issues in CI Pipeline and CD Pipeline, Removed failed pipelines and ran new pipeline.
**CD - succeed.**